# Marmalade Sdk Resolution of Screen Size

Tags: c++, ios, mobile, marmalade

I'm mobile game developer on Marmalade newly. So I wanna get screen **height** and **width** for resolution of different screen size. What's difference between `Iw2DGetSurfaceWidth()` and `IwGxGetScreenWidth()`, is it totaly the same or if not which one is better?

Comment: "which one is better" is not a good question here.

Comment: @JanDvorak But the question is meaningful (although perhaps not phrased in the best possible way). According to [this](https://www.madewithmarmalade.com/devnet/forum/iwgxgetdevicedisplayscreenwidth-and-height-3), there is a clear difference between the two functions.

Comment: "What's the difference between X and Y?" is perfecly fine. "Which one is better?" isn't.

Comment: "what's the difference between a smart car and an SUV"? -- "They are both cars, but <a semi-huge list of pros and cons>"; "which one is better?" -- "Well, do _you_ prefer low energy consumption, or the ability to drive on rocks?"

Comment: You can get difference from name and you can use NSLog to log width from Iw2DGetSurfaceWidth() and IwGxGetScreenWidth().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IwGx and its subcomponents use three different types of surfaces.

1. Device, which holds the width and height of the device, without worrying about the screen orentation.
2. Screen, which is the same as Device but switches the width and height when the device orientation is changed.
3. Surface, which is made by the programmer. It's up to you to create surfaces. A screen can have several surfaces or none at all, like images. Its a rectangular object used for the UI.

For more information you can look it up in the documentation:

http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/native/api_reference/iwgxapidocumentation/iwgxapioverview/screenmanipulation.html

and

http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/native/api_reference/iw2dapidocumentation/iw2dapioverview/usingsurfaces.html